# Executing a query in SQLite within xcode

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite, nsarray

Am i doing this right, because the array is returning a count of 0.

```
-(NSArray *)getAllFavourites{
NSMutableArray *arrFavourites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM  tbl_favourites;";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW ){
        char *charSymbols = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *strFetchedSymbol = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:charSymbols];
        DBClassFavourites *dbClassFav = [[DBClassFavourites alloc] initWithString:strFetchedSymbol];
        [arrFavourites addObject:dbClassFav];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
NSLog(@"%i",[arrFavourites count]);
return arrFavourites;
}
```

I also have this class which initialises the variables needed.

```
 @implementation DBClassFavourites
 -(id) initWithString:(NSString *)symbol
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    self.strSymbol = symbol;
}
return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
[strSymbol release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

This is where it all gets called, from my firstviewcontroller init function

```
 @implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

 arrFavourites = [[DatabaseManager database] getAllFavourites];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use [FMDB wrapper](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx)

To find an error in your code you need to post whole database initialization method

Comment: Check this tutorial carefully. All steps are required (create db skeleton,add it to its project, copy db from bundle, open db,execute query ) http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/